# how to convert an object to json in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

```
<WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=False)>
Public Shared Function GetallForGrid(ByVal dataTableViewModel As DataTableViewModel) As JsonResult

    Dim j As New A
    j.draw = draw
    j.recordsFiltered = count
    j.recordsTotal = count
    j.data = dt.Select()

    Return JsonResult(j)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at Newtonsoft.Json ?

Comment: How can I use it?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json, just add it from menu Manage Nugget Package..

And then in code, you `Imports Newtonsoft.Json`. And for output, you can try this (from your example code):

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j)
```

That JsonConvert.SerializeObject return as string.